# JVM error while installing clearcase

Tags: clearcase

I am unable to install ClearCase version 8.0.3 in RHEL7.
I have installed all the dependencies, and yet it still shows error.

While doing `./launchpad.sh` under the path `/Clearcase/Setup/disk1/`, it opens in Mozilla and shows the added error.

```
JVM error while installing clearcase
```

When I install through `/Clearcase/Agent/` with `./install`, it installs version 1.7.2 and does not shows list of versions when I click on show all versions.

How can I get pass this error message?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the exact error you have.
For instance, following [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21370393), you could see:

> `launchpad.sh` script generates this error:

```
JVM Terminated. Exit Code=1
```

[image: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21370393&aid=1]

> Clicking Close on the GUI pop-up window then reports this error:

```
Error loading: /cc71bin/disk1/InstallerImage_linux/jre_5.0.3.sr8a_20080811b/jre/bin/classic/libjvm.so: 
cannot restore segment prot after reloc: Permission denied
```

That is because:

> This might occur if Secure Linux (SELinux) is enabled.
>
> To disable SELinux:
>
> Edit the file `/etc/selinux/config`.
>
> Change the line "`SELINUX=enforcing`" to "`SELINUX=disable`" or "`SELINUX=permissive`", and then reboot the machine.

Comment: See also RHEL documentation on SELinux: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-sel-enable-disable.html